# Get params from angular $http in Codeigniter controller

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I am new to angular.So i dont know i am doing it in the right way.I am working in codeigniter along with angular.I need to get the id which i was passing though the angular `$http` service in my codeigniter controller.. I didn't get any console errors. Simply the data is not returning.. This is my angular controller

```
app.controller("newsController_id",function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
$http({ method:'POST',
                url:'Controller1/get_list_id',
                params:{id:$routeParams.id}
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.blogs_id = response.data;    
            })
```

codeigniter controller

```
public function get_list_id() {
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        //$id='6';
        $data = $this->Blog_model->getAll_id($id);
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
    }
```

There are no errors in the codeigniter model and view pages..since i got my result perfectly when i hardcoded the id value as 6.But no output when i posting the id.help me solving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing wrong way to pass data angujarjs to codeigniter.
if you want to pass data in **POST** method pass object in $http service on data section like below

**AngularJS Code**

```
$http({
       method:'post',
       url:'/login',
       dataType:"json",
       data:{"vEmail":$scope.vEmail,"vPassword":$scope.vPassword},
}).then(function(suc){
       console.log(suc);
},function(err){
       console.log(err);
});
```

**Codeigniter Code**

```
$vEmail = $this->input->post('vEmail');
$vPassword = $this->input->post('vPassword');
```

If you want to pass data usgin **GET** you should be pass data in Param section like below

```
$http({
       method:'get',
       url:'/login',
       dataType:"json",
       params:{"vEmail":$scope.vEmail,"vPassword":$scope.vPassword},
}).then(function(suc){
       console.log(suc);
},function(err){
       console.log(err);
});
```

you can get that in codeigniter using get method like below

```
$this->input->get('vEmail');
```

Comment: great..solved my issue..and in the second set of code(GET)the method u mean is GET right?

Comment: @Learner second code for GET method. i can't understand what you say on the second comment.
"but the POST set of code is not working"

Comment: what i mean is the code u given to post method is not woring..:-(

Comment: bro..GET is working fine..I mean the code for POST method is not working..(first set of code)

Comment: that's the standard way to send data from angularjs to any server, can you plz share code on plunker or share google dirve link.

Comment: maybe some king of error i had done...any way dont bother about it..i will figure it out..And thanks 4 ur answer..one last help..could you provide me some codeigniter+angular tutorial

Answer (score 1):

in order to get the post variables from angular you need use the following code

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$myData = json_decode($postdata);
```

instead of `$id=$this->input->post('id');`

so your `$id = $myData->id;`

Your final code would look like this:
public function get_list_id() {

```
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
    $myData = json_decode($postdata);
    $id = $myData->id;
        //$id='6';
        $data = $this->Blog_model->getAll_id($id);
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
    }
```

Comment: sorry...simos nothing happens

Comment: @Learner do you see from your browser insector that the variable is posted ? press F12 and goto Network and see if the variable posted has filled the number you want first.

Comment: @simos-get_list_id?id=3..yeah i got the right number i wanted in the network

Comment: that sounds like you get it like $_GET if you see it like this. The $_POST method should not be visible on URL. Out of curiosity could you do var_dump($this->input->get()); and see if you can see your value there?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=blog_id%20in%20blogs_id&p1=string:r

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the data by `$_POST` or `$this->input->post` , You should have something like this in constructor:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$this->request = json_decode($postdata);
```

Now In controller, you can access the `id`:

```
$id = $this->request->id;
```

But it has a problem, you can't use Codeigniter **form validation**, because it works with `$_POST` superglobal. You can do something like this instead (in constructor):

```
$objectRequest = json_decode( file_get_contents("php://input") );
$this->request = xss_clean( json_decode(json_encode($objectRequest), true) );
$_POST = $this->request;
```

But this time you can access to id by the following example:

```
$id = $this->request['id'];
```

Comment: Still got nothing vahid..And thanks to the new information

Comment: In controller do this and see what is the result: `exit(json_encode($this->request));`

Comment: dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater i got this error in console:-)

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=blog_id%20in%20blogs_id&p1=string:r

Comment: You can use `track by $index` into ng-repeat. Btw, you can accept the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: yeah helped me..but i didn't solved it..i couldn't upvote since my reputation is less than 15..:-p

Comment: Yes, understood. Np!